# Finding the eigenvectors of a specific linear map.

Tags: linear-algebra, matrices, linear-transformations

I have $T$ where $T$ is a linear map from $V$ to itself, with $V$ being a linear space of finite dimension $n \geq 2$. In this case, $V$ and $\{0\}$ are the only $T$-invariant spaces.

Does $T$ have any eigenvectors?

Comment: Suppose that $T$ did have an eigenvector $v$. What would $T(\text{Sp}\{v\})$ be?

Comment: @pg_star Presumably "Sp" means the span, but this is not common notation (as far as I know) and should be clarified.

Comment: @pg_star also, at this point you should probably just make that comment into an answer, since there isn't much more to say